# Can I sort a 2D array without having a comparator function?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array and the value I want to sort by is in the array[0][0]...array[0][n] position.  Can I just call Arrays.sort(array) without implementing a comparator function?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. If you want the first row sorted just `Arrays.sort(array[0]);`

Comment: What kind of array is it? An `int[][]`?

Comment: It's a  String[10][2] but the first element of each column is an int and the second is a String.  I want to sort as I stated above but I also need the String associated with the integer to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do it. Next time, try it and see. Loop through the array by row, and then just sort each one individually.

```
int[][] array = new int[5][10];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
    array[i] = Arrays.sort(array[i])
}
```

Here's the docs if for [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) for more information on the method in the `java.util.Arrays` class.

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array, there are ways to do it without a `Comparator`, but a `Comparator` is the easiest way:

In Java 8:

```
String[][] table = {{"5", "A"}, {"2", "B"}, {"4", "C"}, {"1", "D"}, {"3", "E"}};
Arrays.sort(table, Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[0])));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(table));
```

In earlier versions:

```
String[][] table = {{"5", "A"}, {"2", "B"}, {"4", "C"}, {"1", "D"}, {"3", "E"}};
Arrays.sort(table, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(arr1[0]), Integer.parseInt(arr2[0]));
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(table));
```